# How to solve issue of menu i responsive which used in container?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to ask that if i took menu in container. But when I'm checking for that in mobile view not getting menu in full width because that's in container. So How can i take up and can make it in full view.

Current View.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMnmJ.png)

Expected View.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNKsd.png)

I have tried it by taking position absolute but not getting done by that way.. If have smart way to get this solve out then suggest me.

Comment: Could you share your code, not just an image?

Comment: can you share you code or live demo so we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your CSS, put this code :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

So, you can customized all of your element easier.

In this way, you also get your container without any space, both padding nor margin.

Comment: It's work but it effects whole page contents. I want only change in dropdown menu in mobile view.. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Okay, just make sure your container class not used in other place. Just replace `*` with `body > .container `

Comment: I have used .container-fluid class. I have cheked for this. But padding still taking place..

Comment: @UmangPatel How about this : `.container-fluid { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }` .